# What is the best way to define a struct which is only needed by a certain class?

Tags: c++, struct

Given the following simplified class which contains a vector of `MyStruct` objects, where should I define `MyStruct` assuming that it's only being used inside of `Foo` and should not be seen or used from outside?

```
class Foo
{
  std::vector<MyStruct> array;
};
```

Two possibilities I've come across are putting the definition of `MyStruct` right inside of `Foo` or using an anonymous namespace.

Comment: I'd go with right inside Foo, but it is even better if the implementation of Foo is behind an impl pointer.

Comment: Would the `pimpl idiom` be the only good way to avoid defining `MyStruct` completely inside the header file?

Comment: you could make the (private) `array` a type of `std::vector<MyStruct*>` (or smarter `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyStruct>>`) and pre-declare `MyStruct` before the `array`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If array is in any way a public part of `Foo` interface, declare MyStruct like this:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    struct MyStruct { /* stuff */ };
    /* ... */
};
```

Otherwise: declare it in the private section of `Foo`.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you *have* to define it in `Foo`, since it has to
be completely defined before you use it to instantiate
`std::vector`.  Otherwise, it depends; I'd tend to define it in
a private namespace: an unnamed namespace in the implementation
file if all of the functions are in a single source file,
otherwise in a private, implementation header file in a private
namespace (e.g. `FooPrivate`) if they aren't.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want it to be used outside Foo, then the best way is to declare it in the private section of `Foo`

```
class Foo
{
    struct My_Struct;
}
```